# Add a Profile Picture in form in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-profile

I am creating a form in which I need a Profile picture of the user and I want that the picture is in a circle or a ectangular form. By default the area of image should be black or a dummy picture. When the user clicks on the area then he/she is allowed to select an image, just like the profile picture upload in Facebook or Twitter.

[image: Like This]

**My Form**

**HTML**

```html
<div class="signup-w3ls">
    <div class="signup-agile1">
        <form action="#" method="post">
        
            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="header">Profile Photo:</label>
                
                <input id="image" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="header">Store Name :</label>
                <input type="text" id="store_name" name="store_name" placeholder="Store Name" title="Please enter your First Name" required="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="header">Store Type :</label>
                <input type="text" id="store_type" name="store_type" placeholder="Store Type" title="Please enter your Last Name" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="header">Owner Type :</label>
                <input type="text" id="owner_type" name="owner_type" placeholder="Owner Type" title="Please enter a valid email" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="header">Website :</label>
                <input type="url" id="website" name="website" placeholder="Website" id="password1" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="header">Contact Number :</label>
                <input type="text" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Contact Number" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="header">Contact Email :</label>
                <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Contact Email" required="">
            </div>
            
            <input type="submit" class="register" value="Register">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.signup-w3ls {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 70px 25% 80%;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
.signup-agile1{
    width:100%;
    float:center;
}

.signup-w3ls .signup-agile1 .form-control {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
label.header {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 215px;
    color: grey;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:justify;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
input#image,input#store_name, input#store_type,input#owner_type, input#website,input#contact_number,input#contact_email {
    padding:0 40px;
    width:40%;
    height:55px;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    color: grey;
    text-align:justify;
    outline: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -o-border-radius:30px;
    -ms-border-radius:30px; 
}
input#image:focus,input#store_name:focus, input#store_type:focus,input#owner_type:focus, input#website:focus,input#contact_number:focus,input#contact_email:focus  {
    background-color:#f5f8fa !important;
    border:1px solid #dadada;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: grey;
} 
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: grey;  
} 
input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: grey;  
} 
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
color: grey;  
}
.register {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width: 52%;
    height: 55px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 233px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-radius: 30px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}   
.register:hover {
    background-color:#36b051;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:-** https://jsfiddle.net/7ao1qxLe/

Comment: you'll have to research the twitter/facebook APIs and figure out how exactly to do that -- its a multi-step process that cant be answered in a single thought

Comment: no i just give u example of twitter and facebook, i want the image uploader

Comment: That is also a multi-step process -- you'll need to have a back-end implementation using PHP or some other server-side language to store the photo ... which will have to be submitted to the backend via  either a FORM or  via `ajax` first, then you'll also probably need a `database` to store all the different user profiles

Comment: yes, but brother i need only design, i am php and mysql expert

Comment: so, i say that can u help me to give me design of only profile uploader

Comment: i am working on project in which the requirement is this, and i am not able to create it, so here i am to get some tips

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Maybe add a sentence that has a `question`  to the end of your post so we know what your asking?  stackoverflow is a  `question` and `answer` about coding service, not a `code writing` service :)

Comment: @Nakhhhh please check the answer. It may help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you can do is to **hide the input** and just **act as if it was clicked** when the profile image is clicked:

```js
$("#profileImage").click(function(e) {
    $("#imageUpload").click();
});
```

```css
#imageUpload
{
    display: none;
}

#profileImage
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<image id="profileImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" 
       name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
```

## Image preview

You can also give the user a preview of the uploaded image:

```
function previewProfileImage( uploader ) {   
    //ensure a file was selected 
    if (uploader.files && uploader.files[0]) {
        var imageFile = uploader.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();    
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            //set the image data as source
            $('#profileImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }    
        reader.readAsDataURL( imageFile );
    }
}

$("#imageUpload").change(function(){
    previewProfileImage( this );
});
```

**Efficiency note:** You can make it more efficient if you use `createObjectURL` instead of reading data as URL.

```
function fasterPreview( uploader ) {
    if ( uploader.files && uploader.files[0] ){
          $('#profileImage').attr('src', 
             window.URL.createObjectURL(uploader.files[0]) );
    }
}
```

As you can see here in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), the `URL.createObjectUrl` will just generate the URL for the file instead of having to load it into the DOM, which is definitely preferable for large files.

## Circular image crop

To display the image cropped in a circle, you will need to give it an outer `div` and apply `border-radius` to it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="profile-container">
   <image id="profileImage" src="aDefaultImage.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#profile-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

## Complete solution

This snippet puts together all three steps:

```js
$("#profileImage").click(function(e) {
    $("#imageUpload").click();
});

function fasterPreview( uploader ) {
    if ( uploader.files && uploader.files[0] ){
          $('#profileImage').attr('src', 
             window.URL.createObjectURL(uploader.files[0]) );
    }
}

$("#imageUpload").change(function(){
    fasterPreview( this );
});
```

```css
#imageUpload
{
    display: none;
}

#profileImage
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#profile-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#profile-container img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-container">
   <image id="profileImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" 
       name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
```

Comment: brother, it is showing me default picture but it can't show me dialogue window, in which i can select picture

Comment: after selection of image, the image is remain same, a default image

Comment: Try the complete solution I have just added to my answer. The first snippet is only for the file upload triggering. The final solution contains the preview.

Comment: Can you help me to sort out this problem, Please?

Comment: Excellent code.. just used on my site and works flawlessly !!

Comment: How to access selected filename in server side

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#profileImage").click(function(e) {
    $("#imageUpload").click();
});

function fasterPreview( uploader ) {
    if ( uploader.files && uploader.files[0] ){
          $('#profileImage').attr('src', 
             window.URL.createObjectURL(uploader.files[0]) );
    }
}

$("#imageUpload").change(function(){
    fasterPreview( this );
});
```

```css
#imageUpload
{
    display: none;
}

#profileImage
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#profile-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#profile-container img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-container">
   <image id="profileImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" 
       name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert Image tag separately with default image then read the URL while selecting image through input tag.

```
<img id="profile" src="default.png" alt="profile-image" />
```

```html
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#profile').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    
    $("#image").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
        //other uploading proccess [server side by ajax and form-data ]
    });
```

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/7ao1qxLe/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to apply this picture selector

```
<img id="idcardfront" src="images/UploadImgPlaceholder.png" data-type="editable" />
<script>
$("#idcardfront").each(function (i, e) {
var _inputFile = $('<input/>')
.attr('type', 'file')
.attr('hidden', 'hidden')
.attr('id', 'idCardFrontFile')
.attr('onchange', 'readImage()')
.attr('data-image-placeholder', e.id)
.attr('Class', 'hidden');
 $(e.parentElement).append(_inputFile);
 $(e).on("click", _inputFile, triggerClick);
 });
</script>
```