# Click on image to upload image

Tags: html, angular

I have this code in jQuery:

```js
$("#profileImage").click(function(e) {
    $("#imageUpload").click();
});
```

and this is the HTML:

```html
<image id="profileImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
<input id="imageUpload" type="file"  name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
```

how can I replicate it in Angular 4?

EDIT:
from the first comment i see my question is not clear.

I would like to create an "edit the profile image, if clicked on the image".
this will open the "select file popup"

here is the example made with jQuery [Add a Profile Picture in form in HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406509/add-a-profile-picture-in-form-in-html-and-css)

i would like to do it in angular 4

thank you

Comment: you can use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to get an html element in your Angular component, [here is some implementation example from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34636472/6638533)

Answer (score 0):

so i have the answer, can be used just plain javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputPhoto');
input.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // no need for extra code here
    console.log('click triggered');
});

input.click(); // opening dialog
```

ps: community there is no need for downvote if you don't know the answer. just ignore. someone will have the same issue one day and this will come in handy.