# css - how to add Background Image as background with a span above it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to make a button like this
[image]

This is my current progress
[image]

I want to know how to add a background image without blocking the text and icon above.

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

import CloudUploadOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CloudUploadOutlined";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="photo__wrapper__img"
      >
        <div className="__photo__wrapper__img__label-container">
          <div>
            <CloudUploadOutlinedIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
          </div>
          <span>Click here to change photo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.photo__wrapper__img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(60, 67, 74, 0.5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.photo__wrapper__img .photo__wrapper__img__label-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-volhard-747zr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406509/add-a-profile-picture-in-form-in-html-and-css/41406599) is already a similar way of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

`PersonIcon` is a component. Not a url so you should put it into outside background.
And using position `absolute` for your text detail.

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cache-8jghq?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: No, I attached `profile.png` inside the src folder. I will use it as background image