# How to fetch/map profile picture from azure ad b2c in edit profile user flow?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to SignIn/SignUp , edit profile through Azure AD B2C using user flows with .Net core application.
SignIn/SignUp are working perfectly fine. Now I want to implement Edit Profile functionality which is also quite working fine. I want to add one new field in the edit policy called profile image i.e. to fetch the profile image of the user from b2c which can then be edited / updated using edit policy.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

I tried to find out on how to map the user profile picture but didn't work out.

Comment: can you provide the code/custom policies you are implementing

Comment: I am not using any custom policy , user Flows are being used for sign in , signup, edit profile

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create profile image in edit policy.

- I created an Edit user flow:

[image]

In user attributes tab, added a new attribute ProfileImage,

[image]

But it has only data type of String , Boolean and Int

[image]

So , we can customize the edit profile policy , by creating a new policy to edit and by creating custom page layout.

[image]

Create one custom html page to upload image :refered from [javascript - Add a Profile Picture in form in HTML and CSS - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406509/add-a-profile-picture-in-form-in-html-and-css)

**Example:**

```
Uploadimage.html:
function fasterPreview( uploader ) {
    if ( uploader.files && uploader.files[0] ){
          $('#profileImage').attr('src', 
             window.URL.createObjectURL(uploader.files[0]) );
    }
}



$("#imageUpload").change(function(){
    fasterPreview( this );
});

<style>
#imageUpload
{
    display: none;
}

#profileImage
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#profile-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#profile-container img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
</style>
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-container">
   <image id="profileImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" 
       name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>   

</html>
```

Upload it in the storage container with public access or read only blob access.

[image]

And enable cors to reach the B2c domain by giving `https://<tenantdomain>.b2clogin.com` in allowed origins
, select allow methods according to requirement.

[image]

**Copy the blob url and check if its showing the desired page:**

[image]

Run it in the browser:
***`https://stforb2c.blob.core.windows.net/myimagecontainer/uploadimages.html`***

[image]

- Then Go to `B2C_1_editprofile` policy, select profile edit layout name.
- Turn Use custom page content to ON state.
- Paste the blob image upload url in the Custom page URI
  [image]

Save it , then you can see it enabled > **`yes`** in the cutom layout .

[image]

Recheck the url and paste the desired html layout url and save and run the user flow to check the edit profile policy .

```
https://xxxb2c.b2clogin.com/xxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_edit&client_id=1cf9d6aaxxx4d03-8418-2cxe=defaultNoncex&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxb2c.b2clogin.com%2Fkavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Foauth2%2Fauthresp&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

[image]

**References:**

1. [JavaScript and page layout versions - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow)
2. [Customize the look and feel of your Azure AD B2C page - DEV Community](https://dev.to/425show/customize-the-look-and-feel-of-your-azure-ad-b2c-page-30m6)

Comment: Can we also include other inbuild user attributes like given name , etc.   along with the image property in edit profile policy?

Comment: In that case one can  try to create two different policy , one is built-in where all user attributes like given name can be edited and the profile pic edit for other

Comment: So I think the conclusion is like we cannot manage all the user attributes along with image in a single edit profile policy ?

Comment: we can if we can write script for all functionalities that also includes user attributes.see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow#javascript-samples). Also check if this [user attribute configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-user-attributes-input-type) can be  given along with custom layoutthat can help you..